# Can I use "powered by Ubuntu" stickers legally?

Tags: 14.04, legal, education

I recently installed Ubuntu (the 14.04, not any edubuntu or any other ubuntu flavour) in my college lab desktops.

I was willing to put a **"powered by Ubuntu"** sticker on all of them.

I want to know are there any legal issues involved to print Ubuntu stickers by myself and use paste them on cpu cabinet for non-commercial (in fact educational) purpose?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about legal advice.

Comment: @Mateo I didn't know where exactly to ask, can you suggest me where to ask such type of questions?

Comment: ask Canonical directly, it was in the link I posted eariler: http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/contact-us